# Obtaining Endpoint for a CXF client for ws-security

Tags: cxf

I'm writing a CXF client. Now I have to integrate security. 
 I'm having these classes generated from wsdl2java: `MyService`, `MyServiceProxy`, `MyServiceHttpBindingStub`, `MyServiceHttpService` and `MyServiceHttpServiceLocator`.

Until now I was using the `MyServiceProxy` class for making requests to the service. Following the manual, I must somehow obtain an `Endpoint` so I can do this:

```
endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

In the manual it's explained by using the `ClientProxy` helper class like this:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();
```

But how to properly create the `port` from my classes? When I do:

```
MyService port = (new MyServiceHttpServiceLocator()).getMyServiceHttpPort();
```

and put that port to the ClientProxy method, I get a runtime error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not a proxy instance
```

So, how can I obtain the port so that I'd be able to pass it to `ClientProxy.getClient()`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating an instance of the service, and then retrieving the port from that instance?  There's an example of how to get the port another way at the Apache CXF link below, in the section labelled "Logging Messages - for programmatic client side logging".  Note that depending on which version of CXF you are using, the steps may be different.  Another recommendation is to use a configuration file, if possible in your case.  See the security examples in the samples directory.
[Debugging and Logging](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html)

```
 MyService ws = new MyService();
    MyPortType port = ws.getPort();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
```

Comment: aren't the first two lines exactly equivalent to the line:
    MyService port = (new MyServiceHttpServiceLocator()).getMyServiceHttpPort();

Answer (score 1):

Getting the SOAP port works (without cast):

```
MyService service= new MyService(SERVICE_URL, SERVICE_NAME);
Operation port = service.getMyServiceSOAP12Port();
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
```